# Cannot connect to a Windows pc in a Linux network

Tags: networking, server

I have a network running here on a Ubuntu server. A DHCP and a DNS server are running. I now have one Windows computer in that network and several computers with Ubuntu installed. I can ping and have access to its shared hard drives with some Ubuntu computers.  However with two of the computers (including the server) I cannot connect to the Windows computer.

If I do an `nmap` I can't find it. And I can't ping it.

As I did an `arp -a -n` I could find it but that doesn't help me.

Looking forward to your help and sorry for my bad English.

EDIT:`nmap -sn 192.168.2.0/24` did not work
`sudo nmap 192.168.2.0/24` gave me

```
Nmap scan report for 192.168.2.21

Host is up (0.0018s latency).
Not shown: 987 filtered ports
PORT      STATE  SERVICE
16992/tcp closed amt-soap-http
49157/tcp open   unknown
49158/tcp open   unknown
49159/tcp closed unknown
49163/tcp closed unknown
50000/tcp closed ibm-db2
50300/tcp closed unknown
50636/tcp closed unknown
50800/tcp closed unknown
54328/tcp closed unknown
56738/tcp closed unknown
58080/tcp closed unknown
61900/tcp closed unknown
MAC Address: ***
```

Comment: Have you installed `winbind`?

Comment: i can't see the reason for this because on some computers its actually working fine using the shared drives

Comment: The accepted answer indicates the problem is not related to Ubuntu. The problem was caused by incorrect setup of ZoneAlarm in the Windows PC. This question should be closed.

Comment: how to close or delete this question because its obviously not necessary

Comment: @m0rtuu: don't do anything...  The question is being closed as "off topic"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the custom firewall ZoneAlarm on the Windows-PC was blocking everything